# adding rows in datasets for missing values with R

Tags: r, dataset, rows, tidyr, extend

I am working with R.
i have a list of datasets where each of those sets should have a row length 5 for each month (Jan-May). it should look like this:

```
data.frame(name = rep("B", 5), 
           doc_month = c("2022.01", "2022.02", "2022.03", "2022.04", "2022.05"), 
           i_name = rep("Aa",5), 
           aggregation = rep("34"), 5)
```

but some of my datasets dont have data for certain months, or are completely empty, and therefore have a shorter row length/no rows at all. like this:

```
data.frame(name = "A", 
           doc_month = "2022.01", 
           i_name = "Aa", 
           aggregation = "34")
```

I would like to extend each dataset, even empty ones, with the specific months , copy all the other information into the row and put a 0 for aggregation.

I tried to use extend and complete by tidyr but couldnt make it work.

Answer (score 1):

With tidyr's `complete` with purrr's `reduce` to add more dataframes.

Also tweaked `aggregation = rep(34, 5)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(name = rep("B", 5), 
                  doc_month = c("2022.01", "2022.02", "2022.03", "2022.04", "2022.05"), 
                  i_name = rep("Aa",5), 
                  aggregation = rep(34, 5))

df2 <- data.frame(name = "A", 
                  doc_month = "2022.01", 
                  i_name = "Aa", 
                  aggregation = 34)

reduce(list(df1, df2, df1), bind_rows) |> 
  complete(doc_month, nesting(name, i_name), fill = list(aggregation = 0))
#> # A tibble: 15 × 4
#>    doc_month name  i_name aggregation
#>    <chr>     <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 2022.01   A     Aa              34
#>  2 2022.01   B     Aa              34
#>  3 2022.01   B     Aa              34
#>  4 2022.02   A     Aa               0
#>  5 2022.02   B     Aa              34
#>  6 2022.02   B     Aa              34
#>  7 2022.03   A     Aa               0
#>  8 2022.03   B     Aa              34
#>  9 2022.03   B     Aa              34
#> 10 2022.04   A     Aa               0
#> 11 2022.04   B     Aa              34
#> 12 2022.04   B     Aa              34
#> 13 2022.05   A     Aa               0
#> 14 2022.05   B     Aa              34
#> 15 2022.05   B     Aa              34
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this is not very practical becuase I have a list of 72 datasets...so I cant join all of them...unless there is a way?

Comment: Yes, use `reduce`.  See update above.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a skeleton dataset with the five months and then join it to each of your partial datasets.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_A <- data.frame(name = "A", 
                     doc_month = "2022.01", 
                     i_name = "Aa", 
                     aggregation = "34")

reference <- data.frame(doc_month = c("2022.01", "2022.02", "2022.03", "2022.04", "2022.05"))

data_A |>
        full_join(reference, by = "doc_month") |> 
        mutate(aggregation = replace_na(aggregation, "0")) |>
        fill(name, i_name)
```

Output:

```r
#>   name doc_month i_name aggregation
#> 1    A   2022.01     Aa          34
#> 2    A   2022.02     Aa           0
#> 3    A   2022.03     Aa           0
#> 4    A   2022.04     Aa           0
#> 5    A   2022.05     Aa           0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! However, I dont understand how to then draw the basic information like name etc to the new rows - I only get NAs.

Comment: You can use `tidyr::fill()` for that. I've updated my answer.